# How to disable css inheritance

Tags: html, css

In my website I have themes(color changes), I made it using css filter "hue-rotate" on the "body" element.

The problem is in one inner element, I want to disable the hue-rotate in that element.

How can i do that?

Comment: what do you mean by inner element?

Comment: <body><div><img></div></body> the img is the inner element

Comment: Can u upload it at jsfiddle.net ... it is much easier to solve issues if code is available

Comment: Set hue-rotate for that element explicitly?

Comment: Your code would be helpful. Please copy and paste it into your question or use a site like pastebin.com

Answer (score 2):

One doesn't directly "disable css inheritance". This is a good thing, because you'd not want to disable all inheritance, as every element is going to have some style applied to it. You wouldn't want your child element to no longer know the width of its body, for example.

What you want to do, is look at the specific style you *don't* want applied, then look for a way to avoid that selector matching that element in the first place. e.g. if your HTML put your image in a different `<section>`, you could skip that one:

```
<body>
    <section id="foo"><img></section>
    <section id="bar"><img></section>
    <section id="baz"><img></section>
</body>
```

Then your CSS rule could apply only to #foo and #baz, but not #bar:

```
#foo, #baz { filter: hue-rotate(90deg); }
```

Going by the doc on this filter:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#hue-rotate()

another option, which is a bit clunky and not one I'd attempt in pure CSS (though it could be done nicely with a preprocessor like sass or less, to keep all your variables organized) is to simply rotate that element back. e.g. if you have:

```
body { filter: hue-rotate(90deg); }
```

Apply a selector however you want to grab that  and rotate it back, so it still has the body's hue-rotate applied, you simply reverse it:

```
body > div > img { filter: hue-rotate(-90deg); }
```

Comment: thank you, i just fix the problem by complete the inner img hue-rotate to 360 which is the same as you Suggested

Comment: That's probably okay for now, though it will get a bit funky if you ever apply a `transition-duration` that applies to both your body and the image. If the body's 90deg and the img -90deg, they'll cancel out the entire tiime and the image will appear to not transition at all. If the img is 270deg, it'll quickly transition way faster than the body, then go back to cancelled. Probably won't matter at all to you, but it's something to keep in mind. Best practice is to just not apply the hue-rotate to the image by the selector, but negative rotation is generally better than -360deg rotation.